# How to set CleanSession capability for SafariDriver in C#?

Tags: c#, cookies, selenium, webdriver, safaridriver

in Java we can initiate the Safari Webdriver without previously stored coookies through the following code:

```
SafariOptions options = new SafariOptions();
options.setUseCleanSession(true);
WebDriver webdriver = new SafariDriver(options);
```

However it seems that the C# bindings of SafariDriver is missing a property for setting up "UseCleanSession". Is there any other way how to initialize SafariBrowser in C# to start with clean profile other than:

1. Initialize the webdriver
2. Navigate to any page on the respective domain
3. Clear the cookies through webdriver

Thanks a lot.
Radek

Answer (score 0):

It is just another capability to set, after all, the various `*Options` classes are just wrappers around the various `DesiredCapibilities` to just make it easier to define them.

Therefore, you can just give it an additional one:

```
options.AddAdditionalCapability("cleanSession", true);
```

(Untested, as I don't use the SafariDriver, but on the face of it, the above should work)

Comment: that doesn't work - I forgot to mention that I already tried it. I tested it as "cleanSession" or "safari.cleanSession" and none of them work